# Python selenium how to loop only over rows containing specific class name

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Set-up:

I'm using Python + Selenium to do some work.

I have a table with the following html,

```
<tbody>
    <tr bgcolor="white" class="TRNORM TRCOLHEADER">...</tr>
    <tr bgcolor="white" class="TRNORM cROW">...</tr>
    <tr bgcolor="white" class="TRNORM cROW">...</tr>
    <tr bgcolor="white" class="TRNORM">...</tr>
    <tr bgcolor="white" class="TRNORM">...</tr> 
</tbody>
```

and I loop over the rows using the following code,

```
table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#formWrapper > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody')
for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath('tr'):
    # code for row follows
```

---

**Issue**

I need to loop over `class="TRNORM cROW"` only.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following **xpath** which will select rows only contains `class="TRNORM cROW"`

```
for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr[@class="TRNORM cROW"]'):
```

Or following `css selector` which will select rows only contains `class="TRNORM cROW"`

```
for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr[class='TRNORM cROW']"):
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop over the elements only with `class="TRNORM cROW"` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  for row in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#formWrapper > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody tr.TRNORM.cROW"):
    # code for row follows
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  for row in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//td/table/tbody//tr[@class='TRNORM cROW']"):
    # code for row follows
  ```

---

Ideally, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  for row in WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#formWrapper > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody tr.TRNORM.cROW"))) :
    # code for row follows
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  for row in WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td/table/tbody//tr[@class='TRNORM cROW']"))):
    # code for row follows
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # code for row follows
  ```